# replace part of HTML page with empty string

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I have a C# web API that replaces some values in an HTML page and converts it to a PDF. I need to hide some parts of the HTML page based on values I'm getting from the database. How can I hide part of HTML page without using JavaScript or Runat?

Consider this is part of my HTML page:

```html
*****
<div id="Term">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <p class="formattext">
            «Term»
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>☒I agree to the Terms and Conditions. Agreement recorded at: «APPLICATIONDATE»</p>>
</div>
*****
```

I am replacing all values between "« »" in my C# class base of some value. I like to hide this div: `<div id="Term">`. I can have all the text as a field and replace it with empty to not show, but I'm not sure what to do with table or ☒ when I hide it.

Is is possible to replace between ***** with an empty string?

I use this, but it's not working:

```js
if (key.Equals(ApplicationDocumentTemplate.Consent, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
  if (value == "") {
    document = document.Replace(string.Format("*****{0}*****", key), value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way, put a soecial character and replace between in HTMl template that That I read and have it as string.

```
   if (application.TermsAndConditions == "")
            {
                int start = htmlTemplate.IndexOf("{");
                int end = htmlTemplate.IndexOf("}");
                string result = htmlTemplate.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);
                htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.Replace(result, "");
            }
```